# Blueimp's File Upload : troubles tracking down an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm using a file manager that relies on blueimp's jQuery File Upload v6.9.2 and an old version of jQuery. Because of undesired interactions I had to update jQuery to the latest version, and everything went well exept for an error that I am unable to find.

When I upload a file, even tho it looks to be uploaded successfully, an error is returned fo some reason and `this._trigger('fail', null, options);` gets triggered.

It is located in my jquery-fileupload.js :

```
_onFail: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, options) {
    options.jqXHR = jqXHR;
    options.textStatus = textStatus;
    options.errorThrown = errorThrown;
    this._trigger('fail', null, options);
    if (options.recalculateProgress) {
        // Remove the failed (error or abort) file upload from
        // the global progress calculation:
        this._loaded -= options.loaded || options.uploadedBytes || 0;
        this._total -= options.total || this._getTotal(options.files);
    }
},
```

The full jquery-fileupload.js of the 6.9.2 version is available [here on Github](https://github.com/baamenabar/jQuery-File-Upload-and-Crop/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js)

I'm asking for some help/detailled suggestions on how to track down this error so I can fix whatever is going wrong, I'm not very experienced in JS and so far I haven't been able to understand why _onFail is getting triggered or even figuring out the right way to display the actual error.

Thank you !

Comment: show the error you are receiving in the console

Comment: i don't know how to do that : /

Comment: press F12 the developers console will appear, upload a file and see if any errors here popup

Comment: Oh okay, nothing shows up on the console, it stays blank. The file gets uploaded but `_onFail` is still getting triggered